# How to auto adjust the ylim of multi-histogram in basic R?

Tags: r, graphics

```
hist(sqrt(runif(100))
    , border = 'red'
    , breaks = seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=21)
    , col = 'red'
    , angle = 45, density=10, xlim=c(0, 1)
  )

hist(1-sqrt(runif(1000))
    , border = 'blue'
    , breaks = seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=21)
    , col = 'blue'
    , angle = 135, density=10, add=T
  )
```

The code like above can not recognize that the ylim of the first plot is too small. Is there a way in basic R to determine the appropriate ylim beforehand so that the first plot can be plotted with the correct ylim?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can precalculate the maximum y height of the second histogram. Suppose you have the data for the second histogram:

```r
b_data <- 1 - sqrt(runif(1000))
```

Then you call `hist` on this data but without plotting it (`hist` silently returns a list-like object of breaks, counts, density etc, but you can specify `plot = FALSE` to get this object without drawing anything).

```
b <- hist(b_data, breaks = seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=21), plot = FALSE)
```

Now your code is essentially as before except you set the `ylim` of your first histogram to the maximum count of the second histogram:

```
hist(sqrt(runif(100))
    , border = 'red'
    , breaks = seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=21)
    , col = 'red'
    , angle = 45, density=10, xlim=c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, max(b$counts))
  )

hist(b_data, 
    , border = 'blue'
    , breaks = seq(from=0, to=1, length.out=21)
    , col = 'blue'
    , angle = 135, density=10, add=T
  )
```

[image]